# Fill SVG with url and apply transition on it

Tags: css, url, svg, transition, fill

i have svg which has a shape and i want to put different images on this shape when i click on links and i want to apply transition when the images changed.

I used fill attribute and put in the fill the url of the image using javascript and the images appeared but i can't apply the transition on fill attribute.

```js
const rect = document.getElementById('logo');
const toggleLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.image-link');

toggleLinks.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
      const fillAttribute = this.getAttribute('data-fill');

     rect.style.setProperty('fill', `url(${fillAttribute})`);
  });
});
```

```css
#logo{
    transition: fill 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<svg  id="logo" viewbox="0 0 322 419.6">
  <path  class="st0"d="M289.9,234.5c31.4-37.8,41.3-91.4,22.8-140.8c-27.9-74.6-111-112.4-185.5-84.5c-48.8,18.3-79.9,60.7-90.9,108                    C36.1,117.6,5.7,268,0.7,318.4c-1.1,10.9-0.6,28.5,5,43.4c17.4,46.6,69.5,69.4,116.1,52c16.1-6,29.4-16.6,39.3-29.2                     c0,0,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.2S258.3,272.5,289.9,234.5z" /> 
  <defs>
      <pattern id="imageFill1" x="0" y="0" width="1"height="1" >
        <image id = "patternImage "xlink:href="images-testing/production.jpg" height="100%"/>
      </pattern>
      <pattern id="imageFill2" x="0" y="0" width="1"height="1">
        <image id = "patternImage "xlink:href="images-testing/branding.jpg"height="100%"/>
      </pattern>
      <pattern id="imageFill3" x="0" y="0" width="1"height="1">
          <image id = "patternImage "xlink:href="images-testing/media.jpg" height="100%"/>
      </pattern>
  </defs>
</svg> 

<h1 style="color:white"><a class="image-link" data-fill="#imageFill1">Production</a></h1>
<h1 style="color:white"><a class="image-link" data-fill="#imageFill2">Branding</a></h1>
<h1 style="color:white"><a class="image-link" data-fill="#imageFill3">Media</a></h1>
```

Comment: What kind of transition effect were you hoping for? Commonly, changes between two `<image>`-type CSS values do not exhibit any transition effect.

Comment: just i want when the image is changing, it changes smoothly

Comment: What kind smooth image change would you like?

Comment: like ease or ease-in-out

Comment: So that sounds like the timing function you'd like, but what kind of transition effect were you hoping for?

Comment: Look, i want when i click on links the images that displayed on the shape to change so when it change from one image to another i want this change is done in smooth way.... Something like changing the background color

Comment: That sounds like could be a cross-fade effect, if you could confirm please?

Comment: yes something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css animations or transitions actually just **interpolate property values** – provided these values can be interpolated:  You can't interpolate between URLs.

Instead you need to stack all images and change their order and opacity to get a cross-fade transition.

```js
const logo = document.getElementById("logo");
const shape = document.getElementById("shape");
const toggleLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".image-link");
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide')

toggleLinks.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener("click", (e)=> {
    const slideID = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-fill");
    const slide =  document.getElementById(slideID);
    // reset previously acive
    slides.forEach(slide=>{
          slide.classList.remove('prev')
          slide.classList.remove('active')
    })
    slide.previousElementSibling.classList.add('prev')
    slide.classList.add('active')
    // change stack order
    logo.append(slide)
  });
});
```

```css
svg{
  width:10em;
}

a{
  cursor: pointer
}

.prev{
    fill-opacity:1;
}

.active {
  animation: fadeIn 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn{
  0%{
      fill-opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="logo" viewbox="0 0 322 419.6">
  <defs>
    <path id="shape" class="st0" d="m289.9 234.5c31.4-37.8 41.3-91.4 22.8-140.8-27.9-74.6-111-112.4-185.5-84.5-48.8 18.3-79.9 60.7-90.9 108-.2.4-30.6 150.8-35.6 201.2-1.1 10.9-.6 28.5 5 43.4 17.4 46.6 69.5 69.4 116.1 52 16.1-6 29.4-16.6 39.3-29.2 0 0 .1-.2.1-.2s97.1-111.9 128.7-149.9z" />
    <pattern id="imageFill1" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
      <image id="patternImage1" href="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="imageFill2" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
      <image id="patternImage2" href="https://picsum.photos/id/236/200/300" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="imageFill3" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
      <image id="patternImage3" href="https://picsum.photos/id/230/200/300" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  
  <use id="slide1" class="slide" href="#shape" fill="url(#imageFill1)" />
  <use id="slide2" class="slide" href="#shape" fill="url(#imageFill2)" />
  <use id="slide3" class="slide active" href="#shape" fill="url(#imageFill3)" />
</svg>

<h2><a class="image-link" data-fill="slide1">Production</a></h2>
<h2><a class="image-link" data-fill="slide2">Branding</a></h2>
<h2><a class="image-link" data-fill="slide3">Media</a></h2>
```

I'm cloning the filled shape with `<use>` elements.
Each image has its own cloned shape filled with the respective pattern fill.

```
  <use id="slide1" class="slide" href="#shape" fill="url(#imageFill1)" />
  <use id="slide2" class="slide" href="#shape" fill="url(#imageFill2)" />
  <use id="slide3" class="slide active" href="#shape" fill="url(#imageFill3)" />
```

We can easily move the current image on top via `svg.append()`.

Comment: it works but i have a problem because the website runs slow when i added this code so what is the reason ?

Comment: but it works perfect alone

Comment: Maybe the actual images are rather huge and could be optimized. Hard to tell without knowing the rest of your page.

Comment: no it runs slow because i move the shape with the uses to another page and the number of uses is 8 so i think this is the reason

Comment: so i'm trying to do the same think but i will make the shape as a mask for the images so i don't need to duplicate the shape